# HttpEroor 500 Backend Error and HttpError 403 using DoubleClick Bid Manager API in python

Tags: python, api, double-click-advertising

I need to create and run some queries as well as get the last reports via DoubleClick Bid Manager API in python, after following the example [get_last_report.py in Github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-bidmanager-examples/blob/master/python/get_latest_report.py) step by step, I always got an `HttpError 500`, like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbm.py", line 202, in <module>
    main(util.setup(args), args.output_directory, QUERY_ID, args.report_window)
  File "dbm.py", line 154, in main
    response = doubleclick_bid_manager.queries().listqueries().execute()
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 856, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1.1/queries?alt=json returned "Backend Error">
```

Also when I tried to run the example [download_line_items.py](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-bidmanager-examples/blob/master/python/download_line_items.py), I got another error `HttpError 403`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_LI.py", line 81, in <module>
    main(util.setup(args), path, request_body)
  File "download_LI.py", line 57, in main
    handler.write(request.execute()['lineItems'].encode('utf-8'))
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 856, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1.1/lineitems/downloadlineitems?alt=json returned "You are not authorized to use DoubleClick Bid Manager API. Please contact dbm-support@google.com.">
```

I already tried different client secret files, but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resovled, the account we connecte need access to DBM. Just need to add the google connection account to DBM for all service operation.

Comment: Bu how did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

This error is very vague, but it always has to be with a tiny error in the request body.

For those in the future:

Check carefully how to create the query body:

https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1.1/queries#resource

More than one time I lost miserable hours debugging... and in the end it was:

- a typo in a key name
- an extra space like: .... `"frequency": "ONE_TIME "`

Hope it helps :)